# Adaptation of the program code (windows 7) to windows 10 / office 10

Tags: excel, vba, parsing, internet-explorer

I have a program (site parsing) , that works fine on windows 7 . Turning to windows 10 / office 10, It revealed  that MSXML is no longer supported and i need to rewrite the program . At the first attempt to rewrite the code, an error appears:

> Run-time error ‘-2147467259(80004005)’ : 
>   Automation error 
>   Unspecified error

In line :

```
Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
```

Old code:

```
Function extractTable(Ssilka As String, book1 As Workbook, iLoop As Long)
   Dim oDom As Object, oTable As Object, oRow As Object
   Dim iRows As Integer, iCols As Integer
   Dim x As Integer, y As Integer
   Dim data()
   Dim vata()
   Dim tata()
   Dim oHttp As Object
   Dim oRegEx As Object
   Dim sResponse As String
   Dim oRange As Range
   Dim odRange As Range

' get page
Set oHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
oHttp.Open "GET", Ssilka, False
oHttp.Send

' cleanup response
sResponse = StrConv(oHttp.responseBody, vbUnicode)
Set oHttp = Nothing

sResponse = Mid$(sResponse, InStr(1, sResponse, "<!DOCTYPE "))

Set oRegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With oRegEx
    .MultiLine = True
    .Global = True
    .IgnoreCase = False
    .Pattern = "<(script|SCRIPT)[\w\W]+?</\1>"
    sResponse = .Replace(sResponse, "")
End With
Set oRegEx = Nothing

' create Document from response
Set oDom = CreateObject("htmlFile")
oDom.Write sResponse
DoEvents

' table with results, indexes starts with zero
Set oTable = oDom.getelementsbytagname("table")(3)

DoEvents

iRows = oTable.Rows.Length
iCols = oTable.Rows(1).Cells.Length

' first row and first column contain no intresting data
ReDim data(1 To iRows - 1, 1 To iCols - 1)
ReDim vata(1 To iRows - 1, 1 To iCols - 1)
ReDim tata(1 To iRows - 1, 1 To iCols - 1)
' fill in data array
For x = 1 To iRows - 1
    Set oRow = oTable.Rows(x)

    For y = 1 To iCols - 1
         If oRow.Cells(y).Children.Length > 0 Then
            data(x, y) = oRow.Cells(y).getelementsbytagname("a")(0).getattribute("href")
                data(x, y) = Replace(data(x, y), "about:", "http://allscores.ru/soccer/")
            vata(x, y) = oRow.Cells(y).innerText

        End If

    Next y
Next x

Set oRow = Nothing
Set oTable = Nothing
Set oDom = Nothing

Set oRange = book1.ActiveSheet.Cells(110, 26 + (iLoop * 21)).Resize(iRows - 1, iCols - 1)
oRange.NumberFormat = "@"
oRange.Value = data

Set odRange = book1.ActiveSheet.Cells(34, 26 + (iLoop * 21)).Resize(iRows - 1, iCols - 1)
odRange.NumberFormat = "@"
odRange.Value = vata

Set oRange = Nothing
Set odRange = Nothing

End Function
```

New Code :

```
  Function extractTable(Ssilka As String, book1 As Workbook, iLoop As Long)
  Dim oTable As Object, oRow As Object
  Dim iRows As Integer, iCols As Integer
  Dim x As Integer, y As Integer
  Dim data()
  Dim vata()
  Dim tata()
  Dim oRange As Range
  Dim odRange As Range
  Dim objIE As InternetExplorer 'special object variable representing the IE browser

 'initiating a new instance of Internet Explorer and asigning it to objIE
Set objIE = New InternetExplorer

'make IE browser visible (False would allow IE to run in the background)
objIE.Visible = False

'navigate IE to this web page (a pretty neat search engine really)
objIE.navigate Ssilka

'wait here a few seconds while the browser is busy
Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

' table with results, indexes starts with zero
Set oTable = objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("table")(3)

DoEvents

iRows = oTable.Rows.Length
iCols = oTable.Rows(1).Cells.Length

' first row and first column contain no intresting data
ReDim data(1 To iRows - 1, 1 To iCols - 1)
ReDim vata(1 To iRows - 1, 1 To iCols - 1)
ReDim tata(1 To iRows - 1, 1 To iCols - 1)
' fill in data array
For x = 1 To iRows - 1
    Set oRow = oTable.Rows(x)

    For y = 1 To iCols - 1
         If oRow.Cells(y).Children.Length > 0 Then
            data(x, y) = oRow.Cells(y).getElementsByTagName("a")(0).getattribute("href")
                data(x, y) = Replace(data(x, y), "about:", "http://allscores.ru/soccer/")
            vata(x, y) = oRow.Cells(y).innerText

        End If

    Next y
Next x

Set oRow = Nothing
Set oTable = Nothing

Set oRange = book1.ActiveSheet.Cells(110, 26 + (iLoop * 21)).Resize(iRows - 1, iCols - 1)
oRange.NumberFormat = "@"
oRange.Value = data

Set odRange = book1.ActiveSheet.Cells(34, 26 + (iLoop * 21)).Resize(iRows - 1, iCols - 1)
odRange.NumberFormat = "@"
odRange.Value = vata

Set oRange = Nothing
Set odRange = Nothing
 'close the browser
objIE.Quit
End Function
```

Comment: I try to test your new code on windows 10 machine. Based on my testing result, I find that I am not getting any error while setting IE object. If you are getting an error on your side than try to set IE object using alternative ways like Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") I suggest you to first try to test simple automation on that machine and after that try to run your original code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of re-writing it to use Internet Explorer you could just update your reference. You were using `MSXML2.XMLHTTP` which no longer exists in Windows 10 because it has been updated to a later version. Try using `MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0` instead

Comment: He is using a late bound call so does that still apply? It poses no problem on Windows 8 versions. I can't test with windows 10 so would be good to know if you have tested.

Answer (score 0):

1) Tools - References ( Choose Microsoft XML, v6.0)

2)Change lines :

Dim oHttp As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

Set oHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")

Now it works . Thank you !